# PowerShell to turn on All network by Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I wrote a power-shell and it is running fine from the windows machine by PS editor. System prompt for my user name to authenticate before running this.

```
$subscription = "dev"
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $subscription
$keyvaultname = "kv-dev"
Update-AzKeyVaultNetworkRuleSet -DefaultAction Allow -VaultName $keyvaultname
```

when I am running the same script in Azure pipelines (using PowerShell task) it is throwing following error. I removed the Connect-AzAccount.

```
Update-AzKeyVaultNetworkRuleSet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

How can I run this from azure pipelines using Power Shell task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the Azure PowerShell commands in pipeline job to manage Azure resources, you should use the [**Azure PowerShell task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) instead of [**PowerShell task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops).

You need to set up an [**Azure Resource Manager service connection**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection) (**ARM connection**) for use on the **Azure PowerShell task**. This **ARM connection** is used as the authentication, and you should not directly set the authentication in the PowerShell scripts.